# How to parse DateTime property from AppEngine in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I need to parse DateTime string coming from AppEngine in Java (Android). The string looks like this: `2011-07-26 17:21:00+01:00`. Is it some standard format? Is there simpler way than using custom `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: A question. Do you have control of the server end? Why not just send the millisecond value (UTC) instead of a human readable string?

Comment: 'Coming from App Engine' where? In a header? In the body?

Comment: No I don't have control of the server end. It's coming from AppEngine datastore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is pretty simple except that for the fact that your date string is a bit off because of the last `:` in there. Just replace the `:` and use the following pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mmZ");
String dateStr = "2011-07-26 17:21:00+0100";
System.out.println(sdf.parse(dateStr));
```

Comment: I know and that's why I did mention it in my post.

Comment: Didn't notice that :) Removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

What can be simpler than SimpleDateFormat in that case? You just have to get rid of that last nasty `:` in the timezone part.

Edit: The format is very close to a standard format.

This will get rid of the last nasty `:`, and parse the date:

```
String data = "2011-07-26 17:21:00+01:00";
data = data.replaceFirst("(.*):(..)", "$1$2");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZZ");
Date parse = formatter.parse(data);
System.out.println("Got " + parse);
```