# com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Invalid date/time format: 2014/08/29

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

One of my class has a field to store a date. Whenever I call the method to insert this object using the google endpoint is fails and return the following message:

com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Invalid date/time format: 2014/08/29

Any idea what the issue is and what to do to get this fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as explained here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844428/2417948

The datetime format is pretty precise for the appengine.  I'd try to use the format presented in the answer I linked.  Should solve your problem :)