# How to set DateTime in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, datetime

So for my App Engine Project, one of the fields has a DateTimeProperty Field, and when I do an insert via an android device, I have no idea how to set the Date in the backend. I have Date and time pickers set up and can easily get the date, but the android generated code for setting the date has object.setDate() of type String, not DateTime. If i pass a string in however, the backend call fails with a 503.

Comment: You have to convert the string to an appropriate type on the backend.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling setDate() and show us the string you are passing. Does it look something like the value in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844280/how-to-parse-datetime-property-from-appengine-in-java-android)